# convert font to string and back again

Tags: c#, winforms, string, fonts, colors

i have an application where my user changes font and font color for different labels etc and they save it to a file but i need to be able to convert the font of the specified label to a string to be written to file, and then when they open that file my program will convert that string back into a font object. How can this be done? I haven't found anywhere that shows how it can be done.

thank you

bael

Comment: as in you want to store the .ttf file in your file ?

Comment: ttf? What i mean is i just need to convert the font information (example: Arial, 12.0, Regular, Green) to a file. and then when i load that file into a string just convert it to a font object

Answer (score 39, accepted):

It is easy to go back and forth from a font to a string and back with the System.Drawing.FontConverter class.  For example:

```
        var cvt = new FontConverter();
        string s = cvt.ConvertToString(this.Font);
        Font f = cvt.ConvertFromString(s) as Font;
```

Comment: According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.fontconverter.aspx) it says _Access the FontConverter class through the TypeDescriptor class by calling the GetConverter method_.  Does this make any difference?

Comment: Not that I can think of, it's just the long way around to read the [TypeConverter] attribute on the Font class and get the exact same converter.  That attribute is never going to change, never +/- 1%

Comment: Good answer. However it's better to use `ConvertToInvariantString` and `ConvertFromInvariantString`. Otherwise the string format looks different in different countries, ie. `Tahoma, 10.5pt` in US vs `Tahoma; 10,5pt` in most European countries.

Answer (score 4):

You can [serialize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms233843%28VS.100%29.aspx) the font class to a file.

See [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/et91as27%28VS.100%29.aspx) for details of how to do so.

To serialize:

```
private void SerializeFont(Font fn, string FileName)
{
  using(Stream TestFileStream = File.Create(FileName))
  {
    BinaryFormatter serializer = new BinaryFormatter();
    serializer.Serialize(TestFileStream, fn);
    TestFileStream.Close();
  }
}
```

And to deserialize:

```
private Font DeSerializeFont(string FileName)
{
    if (File.Exists(FileName))
    {
        using(Stream TestFileStream = File.OpenRead(FileName))
        {
            BinaryFormatter deserializer = new BinaryFormatter();
            Font fn = (Font)deserializer.Deserialize(TestFileStream);
            TestFileStream.Close();
        }
        return fn;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: +1 this is probably the most elegant solution to serialize the entire object.

Comment: Note that you don't have to use the BinaryFormatter and serialize straight to a file, you can use any IFormatter and any Stream.

Answer (score 2):

Quite simple really if you want to make it readable in the file:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Label someLabel = new Label();
        someLabel.Font = new Font("Arial", 12, FontStyle.Bold | FontStyle.Strikeout | FontStyle.Italic);

        var fontString = FontToString(someLabel.Font);
        Console.WriteLine(fontString);
        File.WriteAllText(@"D:\test.txt", fontString);

        var loadedFontString = File.ReadAllText(@"D:\test.txt");

        var font = StringToFont(loadedFontString);
        Console.WriteLine(font.ToString());

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    public static string FontToString(Font font)
    {
        return font.FontFamily.Name + ":" + font.Size + ":" + (int)font.Style;
    }

    public static Font StringToFont(string font)
    {
        string[] parts = font.Split(':');
        if (parts.Length != 3)
            throw new ArgumentException("Not a valid font string", "font");

        Font loadedFont = new Font(parts[0], float.Parse(parts[1]), (FontStyle)int.Parse(parts[2]));
        return loadedFont;
    }
}
```

Otherwise serialization is the way to go.

Comment: I wouldn't bother rolling my own serializer since the Font class is [serializable] already.

Answer (score 0):

First, you can use following article to enumerate system fonts.

```
public void FillFontComboBox(ComboBox comboBoxFonts)
{
    // Enumerate the current set of system fonts,
    // and fill the combo box with the names of the fonts.
    foreach (FontFamily fontFamily in Fonts.SystemFontFamilies)
    {
        // FontFamily.Source contains the font family name.
        comboBoxFonts.Items.Add(fontFamily.Source);
    }

    comboBoxFonts.SelectedIndex = 0;
}
```

To create a font:

```
Font font = new Font( STRING, 6F, FontStyle.Bold );
```

Use it to setup font style etc....

```
Label label = new Label();
. . .
label.Font = new Font( label.Font, FontStyle.Bold );
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code to create a font based on the name and color information:

```
Font myFont = new System.Drawing.Font(<yourfontname>, 9.75F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
Color myColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(<yourcolor>);
```